# pyspark can not use flattened columns

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark df which has been flattened before (no control over that part):

```
root
 |-- pageref: string (nullable = true)
 |-- serverIPAddress: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- time: double (nullable = true)
 |-- timings.blocked: double (nullable = true)
 |-- timings.dns: double (nullable = true)
 |-- timings.connect: double (nullable = true)
 |-- timings.ssl: double (nullable = true)
 |-- timings.send: double (nullable = true)
 |-- timings.wait: double (nullable = true)
 |-- timings.receive: double (nullable = true)
 |-- request.url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- request.headers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

When trying to access any of those flattened fields i got error:

```
df.groupby(F.col("request.url")).count().sort(F.desc("count")).show(20, False)

AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'request.url' given input columns: [date, pageref, request.headers, request.method, request.queryString, request.url,.....
```

Why ? How can i access those fields ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dots in your column names are causing that - try wrapping the column names in backticks, like so:

```py
df.groupby(F.col("`request.url`")).count().sort(F.desc("count")).show(20, False)
```